# Creating Dashboard Charts With Complex Queries In Microsoft Dynamic CRM 2015

Tags: dynamic, charts, crm, dashboard

I need to create dashboard charts using complex query in Microsoft Dynamic Crm 2015 OnPrem. Are there any ways to do it at Dynamic Crm 2015 UI or another ways?

Thanks for your responces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try XrmToolBox, the plugins(Chart Manager and FetchXML Builder) will make your chart build process much more easier.